# Problem when open Heroku, but the webpage just has the bug "The page you were looking for doesn't exist."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am trying to open a web page by using "Heroku open" command, and it just only gave me the error "The page you were looking for doesn't exist."

When I ran those command, I had no problem

`git init
git add.
git commit -am "some comment"
git push heroku master`

I also tried to solve this problem by those command

`heroku run rake db:migrate
heroku run rake db:schema:load`
but nothing changed.

Could you please give me some ideas? Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe contacting heroku customer support will be better. If not, what is the url you are entering?

Comment: please use this command and add server logs in the question too `heroku logs --tail`

Comment: @sonnyhe2002 : the url automatically be changed to `https://a186.herokuapp.com/` a186 is the app I uploaded to web. Do you have any idea for me?

Comment: Does your application have a `root` in the `routes.rb`? Does that root page load locally?

Comment: @spickermann here is my `routes.rb`                    `Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end`

Comment: @spickermann here is my `routes.rb`

 `Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end`

It does not have a `root`, so must I add a `root` in it by hand ? Could you please show me how can I add it by some samples ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can do like root 'users#show' . Where as, users is a controller name and show is a method

Comment: @AnhBui You basically have not defined any route in your application. Therefore Rails don't know what page to show. I advise reading [the Rails guide about Routing](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). Did you define a controller and a model?

Comment: @spickermann As you can see, I did not define a controller and a model in my `routes.rb` , you mean I must use `root to: 'pages#main'` method ?

Comment: @AnhBui: You have an empty routes table and you are saying that you did not create any controller or model. Why do you expect that such a blank Ruby on Rails application is able to render any page?